# Hacer un menu desplegable (css) con un foreach de php

Tags: php, css

quería saber si es posible hacer un menú desplegable a través de foreach php y si es así como hacerlo.

```
$listadoModulos = $usuario->perfil->getModulos();
<?php foreach ($listadoModulos as $modulo): ?>
            <a class="menuitems" href="/xampp/Prueba/modulos/<?php echo $modulo->getDirectorio(); ?>/listado.php">
                <?php echo $modulo->getDescripcion(); ?>
            </a>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Por favor, agrega todo el código relacionado al foreach.

Comment: Un menú desplegable se construye básicamente con HTML y CSS. Con PHP puedes imprimir los valores de cada ítem, pero dependerá de la estructura específica del menú (ej: ¿varios ítems principales que se despliegan en varios subítems?)